# Фильтрация слов в поле ввода на странице

Tags: javascript, html

У меня немного запутанный вопрос из-за того я не знаю как подойти к решению задачи. 
Казалось, что все просто, но я ошибался, поэтому решил спросить, чтобы не изобретать велосипед.
Теперь о самой задаче: на странице есть поле ввода и посетители сайта могут ввести что угодно. 
Надо как-то сообщать пользователю о недопустимых словах. Это надо делать сразу по мере ввода. 
Для этого нужен список стоп-слов. Но наверное с ними будет сложно из-за грамматических ошибок. 
Слов может быть много, их надо загрузить на страницу. Лучше загружать сразу или по частям? 
Когда лучше проводить проверку? В процессе ввода или лучше дождаться завершение ввода? 
Где можно почитать о технологии фильтрации на страницах? 
Помогите советом, но лучше поделитесь примером, чтобы его можно было взять за основу.

В комментарии мне сказали, что это технически невозможно. Но я немного сомневаюсь в невозможности, но если так, то подскажите возможный способ фильтрации.

Comment: В такой постановке задачи по состоянию на 2016 год это технически невозможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса не понятно, с чем именно возникает сложность, но всё-равно попробую ответить.

Я бы делал по аналогии с [автокомплитом](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) с фильтрацией на стороне сервера (т. к. слов может быть очень много). По мере ввода текста на сервер отправляется введённый пользователем текст. Сервер анализирует слова в тексте, сравнивая их с "чёрным списком". Если нехорошие слова найдены, список этих слов возвращается назад в браузер, где их можно подсвечивать в поле ввода или ещё как-то отображать на странице.

Для сравнения слов с опечатками/ошибками используются технологии [нечёткого поиска](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114997/). Выбираете наиболее подходящий алгоритм и реализуете его. Какой именно алгоритм использовать - зависит от конкретно вашей ситуации.

Проблемы могут возникать на конкретных этапах. Например, как отправить только один запрос в один момент времени, медленно считается расстояние Левенштейна, как подсветить слова в поле ввода и т. п.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хотелось бы уточнить: на сервере большой список слов надо держать в памяти постоянно?

Comment: Тут многое зависит от конкретной ситуации. Можно держать их в базе и сравнивать с помощью базы. Можно загрузить из базы в память и сравнивать уже в памяти. Если слов **много**, а памяти мало, то такой подход может не прокатить. Ещё можно кеширование замутить...

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то решение такое:

1. С помощью регулярных выражений (либо массива) определить нужные слова.
2. С помощью библиотеки JQuery и события keyup отслеживать то, что ввёл пользователь.