# Передача данных со страницы в WPF приложение

Tags: wpf, веб-программирование

Есть страница с полем ввода.  Посетитель может ввести текст и нажать отправить.
Этот текст должен попасть к оператору, у которого установлено WPF приложение.
Никак не могу понять как такое можно сделать, чтобы в WPF приложении встроить обработчик запросов?

Мне подсказывает VladD в комментариях, что можно в WPF-приложение встроить обработчики как в не-WPF приложение. 
Знаю как работают веб-приложения. Это подпадает под не-WPF? Но в веб-приложение насколько я знаю невозможно встроить обработчик запросов от самого же приложения. Мне кажется, что такое в принципе невозможно.

Comment: А чем отличается WPF-приложение от не-WPF? Встраивайте точно так же.

Comment: Правильно ли я вас понимаю, что часть программы из вебсервера можно перенести в WPF приложение? Я не слышал про такое. Подскажите где можно почитать подробнее о том, что вы говорите.

Comment: Я не знаю, где почитать, но сервер — такое же приложение. И не совсем понятно, почему у вас «обработчик запросов от самого приложения» — у вас ведь оператор получает запрос от клиента, , так что всё же не «само приложение», а клиент.

Comment: Если клиентское приложение в ваших руках, я бы на вашем месте не заморачивался, и использовал WCF-сервис.

Comment: Глянул документацию по WCF. Час от часу не легче. Есть какой-то простой пример чтобы его взять и применить. Мне говорят что есть, надо только поискать и спросить тех кто знает. Поиски не дали результат, поэтому решил спросить.

Comment: А в чём сложность? Всё проще чем полновесный веб-сервер поднимать. У вас по сути интерфейс с аж одним методом `void Accept(string parameter)`.

Comment: Попробуйте по официальному tutorial'у: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (вот вроде русский перевод: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms734712%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

В WPF приложение оказывается можно встроить сервис, который запускается с помощью метода [WebApp.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.hosting.webapp(v=vs.113).aspx) и обрабатывать входящие веб-запросы без какого-либо использования внешних веб-серверов, включая IIS.
Конструкция на основе встроенного сервиса работает достаточно быстро, позволяя обрабатывать тесячи запросов в секунду, что вполне достаточно для моей [задачи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490641/201326) фильтрации слов, решение которой мне подсказали в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490692/201326).