# Какой объем информации возможно обработать?

Tags: .net, text

Пытаюсь шаг за шагом решать свою основную [задачу фильтрации слов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490641).
Возник вопрос: какое количество слов может одновременно находиться в памяти .NET приложения? Стоит ли держать все слова в памяти, с учетом того, что слов может быть около миллиона и возможно даже больше?

Comment: Миллион слов, даже по 10 букв в каждом, да еще и в юникоде - 20 миллионов байт. 20 Мб - не о чем.

Comment: .NET умеет в ленивые вычисления, поэтому вовсе не обязательно держать весь текст в памяти для его обработки. Пример: `var matchingLines = File.ReadLines("x.txt").Where(l => l.Contains("Мама"); foreach (var l in matchingLines) Console.WriteLine(l);`. Этот код прекрасно работает с файлами, размер которых превышает объём доступного адресного пространства.

Comment: @VladD Вы предлагаете для поиска стоп-слова обращаться к файлу?  Но недавно я читал, что обращение к файлам является бутылочным горлышком. В .NET сделали обходной путь?

Comment: @Grizlov: Нет, не сделали. Но если данные не помещаются в виртуальную память, то их в любом случае придётся из неё куда-то выгружать. Например, на диск.

Comment: @VladD Изначально они на диске записаны. Вопрос о загрузке, и о допустимом количестве, которое может поместиться и быть обработано с приемлемой скоростью, то есть с учетом того, что быстродействие системы не должно деградировать.

Comment: Вопрос в том, данные помещаются _полностью_ в память, или нет? Если помещаются, грузите всё в память, в чём проблема?

Comment: @VladD У любой системы есть ограничения. Когда я спросил о количестве слов, которое может одновременно находиться в памяти .NET, то я спрашивал об ограничениях. Начинать что-либо делать не зная что ждет впереди неразумно. Поэтому я задал вопрос.

Comment: Ну, вы же понимаете, что количество слов ничего не определяет. Слова могут быть разной длины. Загрузите все данные в память и проверьте, не вылетит ли по недостатку памяти, делов-то!

Comment: @VladD Сегодня не "вылетит", завтра тоже "пронесет", но такое полагание на авось не подходит, и выглядит как-то совсем не серьезно. Мне надо знать ограничения заранее.

Comment: @Grizlov: А заранее сказать и невозможно, мало ли сколько у вас других объектов в памяти. Гарантию вам не даст никто, вообще. (И ни один язык программирования.)

Comment: @VladD Почему заранее сказать невозможно? Вы хотите сказать, что в .NET нет метрик, но так как .NET используется в корпорациях, в которых без метрик ничего не делают, то получается, что метрики в .NET есть. И я не спрашивал о гарантиях, а спрашиваю об ограничениях. Можете назвать примерные "цифры" по ограничениям?

Comment: @Grizlov. [вы хотите что-то вроде этого](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296211/how-to-get-the-size-of-available-system-memory)?